# Replace a keyword in href with an input value

Tags: jquery, parsing

I am trying to replace a particular keyword in a href attribute which is taken from an input field. The code is as follows.

// Script

```
$('#fileName').blur(function() {
var saveName = $('#fileName').val();
var appendName = $('#exportFilename').attr("href").replace(/\DEFAULTNAME/g, saveName);
$('#exportFilename').attr("href", appendName);
});
```

//  HTML

```
<input type="text" id="fileName" />
<a id="exportFilename" href="http://127.0.0.1/DEFAULT/REPORTER/typDatabaase.FileName=DEFAULTNAME&typDataase.SelectId-1,2">Download File</a>
```

Thanks in advance

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vXzLc/1/)

Comment: Why do you have a `\ ` in front of the D in `/\DEFAULTNAME/`?

Comment: So? what is the question? "The code's not working", is that the question?

Comment: yes.. i am not getting the updated href value on blur function

Answer (score 0):

The code you have seems to be working for me using the latest version of jQuery.
  The only thing I can suggest is to ensure your jQuery is encapsulated between either `$(document).ready(function() {})` or `$(function() {})`.  Also, you may want to check to make sure you have the most up-to-date version of jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vXzLc/1/

Please find the link.. The first time it works, but when i change the input name to something else the second time, it isnt working..